# Enum or symbols in Perl 6

Tags: perl, raku

I want to pass a parameter to a method which may only have a predefined value.

```
   method send-http($url, $http_method) { .... }
```

Should I create an enum to pass `$http_method`? If so then how?

Or does Perl 6 have something like symbols in Ruby?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to restrict `$http_method` to one of `GET`, `HEAD`, `POST` etc.? I think you want an `enum`, but I don't see the problem with passing a simple string; you can verify that it's one of the valid choices in a test inside `send_http`. I don't understand why you think something like a Ruby symbol would help. The main advantage of symbols is that they're immutable and are very fast in comparisons, but you could just as easily write either `:GIT` or `"GIT"` by mistake and symbols won't protect you from that

Comment: @Borodin. Yes. At least symbols are fast. I believe in Perl 6 there must be something more appropriate than just a string.

Comment: I still don't really understand what problem you're trying to solve

Comment: One way to do it: `enum Method <GET HEAD POST>; method send-http($url, Method $method) { ... }`; you could also go with named arguments

Comment: @Christoph, thanks. Are there other options?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, here is a caveat this will overshadow the `Method` built-in type.

Answer (score 3):

As @Christoph mentioned, you can use enums:

```
enum Method <GET PUT POST>;
sub http-send(str $url, Method $m) { * }

http-send("http://url/", GET);
```

You can also use type constraints:

```
sub http-send(str $url, str $m where { $m ∈ <GET HEAD POST> }) { * }

http-send("http://url/", 'GET');

http-send("http://url/", 'PUT');
Constraint type check failed for parameter '$m'
```

I guess you could also use multi dispatch:

```
multi sub http-send('GET') { * }
multi sub http-send('PUT') { * }
multi sub http-send($m) { die "Method {$m} not supported." }

http-send('GET');

http-send('POST');
Method POST not supported.
```

Comment: what's `∈ `, how can I type it?

Comment: what's ∈ , how can I type it?

Comment: `∈` is the unicode symbol ELEMENT OF
you can also type the Texas variant which is `(elem)`